# How to use LibVLCSharp to stream in game footage from Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, libvlcsharp, vlc-unity

I would like to implement an application that is composed by a server application (built with Unity for Windows), where the actual simulation is running, and a client application (built with Unity for Android) to which the rendered game view is streamed to; in other words I want to do remote rendering in Unity and both ends are implemented with Unity. 
 
I have found, among others, [LibVLCSharp](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp), which looks quite promising.

My questions are:
- Is it actually possible to achieve the indicated functionality with LibVLCSharp and Unity? 
- Does someone know sources where a potentially similar project has been documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: no. 
Second question: there can't be any. 
 
"Unity is not officially supported yet, this was a closed beta test. Unity will be supported in LibVLCSharp 4.0" [source](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/issues/95)

Answer (score 1):

Unity implementation is currently actively being worked on. It hasn't been open sourced yet and doesn't work quite well for now.
Expect communications on LibVLCSharp if we manage to make it work !